# Building relationships in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, networkx

I have a csv file that has 5 columns Sender, Receiver, Weight, Fairness Score (of Sender), Goodness Score (of Receiver).
[image: csv]
I am trying to create a network in NEO4J where goodness is a property of the sender and fairness is the relationship between the sender and the receiver. I also want it to import distinct values because I have senders that are receivers and receivers that are also senders.

Comment: So, what would this look like if you were to show it using http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/?  What sort of queries do you expect to do?

Comment: You describe a `Weight`, but your CSV has a `Rating`. Are these the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for a query to generate data from your file, this is roughly what you want (if you want to avoid duplicate nodes and relationships):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///input.csv' AS row
MERGE(s:Person {id: row.Sender})
SET s.fairness = TOINTEGER(row.`Fairness Score`)
MERGE(r:Person {id: row.Receiver})
SET s.goodness = TOINTEGER(row.`Goodness Score`)
MERGE (s)-[hr:SENDS_TO]->(r)
SET hr.weight = TOINTEGER(row.Weight)
```

*In the future, you need to put much more info into your questions (like what your desired data model is, what you have already tried, and what the results were). And, most importantly, you need to actually state a question!*

Comment: thanks cybersam. I am fairly new to neo4j so im not familiar with the syntax so I couldnt get it to work as required. I know what I want to visualize but I just started using neo4j recently. Basically my model should show relations between raters and receivers on a bitcoin platform (a relation of who trusts who). My model should show nodes(names) in red/green based on the goodness score (of receiver) and the edges should measure the fairness(of sender).

Comment: You should spend more time to learn neo4j, playing with your data, and trying different data models and queries. That is really the only way to develop an understanding. If you have already tried things and they don't work as expected, then provide sufficient detail in your question so that others can understand what you are trying to accomplish, see what code you have tried, and see what errors or bad behavior you have encountered. Otherwise you are very unlikely to get good answers, and may even have your questions closed for poor quality.

Comment: I have tried using your code and made a little bit of modifications and now it works like I want! One last question, is it possible to change the node color based on a goodness score of that node? for example 0 should be red and 1 should be green.
aside from that, thank you so much for the help and I will take all your comments into consideration for the future

Comment: The neo4j Browser does not (currently) have that capability.

Comment: I am now trying to query based on maximum goodness.. I have used this code to build my network: 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///trial.csv' AS row
MERGE(s:Person {id: row.Sender})
MERGE(r:Person {id: row.Receiver})
SET r.goodness = row.`goodness`
MERGE (s)-[hr:SENDS_TO]->(r)
SET hr.fairness = row.fairness

and now I used this to query but it is giving me error variable r is not defined when i write this: 
MATCH (s:Person)
WITH  max(r.goodness) AS maximum
MATCH (s:Person)-[:SENDS_TO]->(r:Person)
WHERE r.goodness = maximum
RETURN s

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use `r` before you have defined it. Also, this is s simplified version of your query: `MATCH (s:Person)-[:SENDS_TO]->(r:Person) WHERE s.goodness = r.goodness RETURN s`. But it does not seem to be returning anything useful. You should create a new question if you still have issues.